# r data.frame not display value

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, type-conversion

Last column on data viewer not visible as well as accessible. I m using moonsun package where planets() function return the data.frame. the last column will show numberical value + text ( "NA Leo"). if we print value of variable it will show "Leo" text in output window. but when we obser value from data frame viewer its will not show. also if we print planets$mag then also it will not show last text column.

```
library(moonsun)
    
planets()
# Print following output
# ra             d phase  angle  dist size  mag    
# 2020-08-19-Sun      9h 54m 45s  12* 41' 55''    NA     NA  1.01  0.5   NA Leo
# 2020-08-19-Moon     9h 48m 30s  13* 19' 31''   0.0  112.2  0.97 32.0   NA Leo
# 2020-08-19-Mercury  9h 58m 12s  14* 16'  7'' 100.0 -151.9  1.36  5.0 -2.0 Leo
```

when store to variable it will not store e.g "Leo" last column but while printing var value it will show in output

```
var=planets()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This package is no longer active on CRAN, so I had to install the most recent version from the archive. The problem is that the object returned from the function `planets()` is *not* a normal data frame. It is a type of S3 object called "eqc" which is basically just a data frame with a modified print method that adds an unnamed final column when it is printed.

```r
planet_df <- planets()

planet_df
#>                             ra             d phase  angle  dist size  mag
#> 2020-08-19-Sun      9h 54m 45s  12* 41' 55''    NA     NA  1.01  0.5   NA Leo
#> 2020-08-19-Moon     9h 48m 30s  13* 19' 31''   0.0  112.2  0.97 32.0   NA Leo
#> 2020-08-19-Mercury  9h 58m 12s  14* 16'  7'' 100.0 -151.9  1.36  5.0 -2.0 Leo
#> 2020-08-19-Venus    6h 44m 23s  20*  8' 37''  53.1   91.6  0.75 22.6 -5.0 Gem
#> 2020-08-19-Mars     1h 34m 19s   5* 19' 33''  89.3   71.2  0.55 17.0 -2.0 Psc
#> 2020-08-19-Jupiter 19h 18m  7s -23* 22' 35''  99.6  -98.1  4.31 45.6 -2.7 Sgr
#> 2020-08-19-Saturn  19h 51m 45s -22* 47' 10''  99.9 -101.2  9.14 18.1  0.9 Sgr
#> 2020-08-19-Uranus   2h 35m 15s  14* 43' 22''  99.9   72.1 19.54  3.4  5.8 Ari
#> 2020-08-19-Neptune 23h 21m 47s  -6* 41' 43'' 100.0   69.5 29.04  2.1  7.8 Aqr
#> 2020-08-19-Pluto   19h  0m 14s -22* 50' 46'' 100.0  -94.2 32.24  0.3 14.1 Sgr

class(planet_df)
#> [1] "eqc"        "apos"       "data.frame"
```

When you look at the `print` method for "eqc", you can see all that it does is call the `constel` function on the data frame and stick this on as an unnamed column:

```
print.eqc
#> function (x, ...) 
#> {
#>     x$" " = constel(x)
#>     print.data.frame(x)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x0f572b08>
#> <environment: namespace:moonsun>
```

So if you want this as just a standard data frame, you could do:

```
planet_df <- as.data.frame(planet_df)
planet_df$cons <- constel(planet_df)
planet_df
#>                             ra             d phase  angle  dist size  mag  cons
#> 2020-08-19-Sun      9h 54m 45s  12* 41' 55''    NA     NA  1.01  0.5   NA   Leo
#> 2020-08-19-Moon     9h 48m 30s  13* 19' 31''   0.0  112.2  0.97 32.0   NA   Leo
#> 2020-08-19-Mercury  9h 58m 12s  14* 16'  7'' 100.0 -151.9  1.36  5.0 -2.0   Leo
#> 2020-08-19-Venus    6h 44m 23s  20*  8' 37''  53.1   91.6  0.75 22.6 -5.0   Gem
#> 2020-08-19-Mars     1h 34m 19s   5* 19' 33''  89.3   71.2  0.55 17.0 -2.0   Psc
#> 2020-08-19-Jupiter 19h 18m  7s -23* 22' 35''  99.6  -98.1  4.31 45.6 -2.7   Sgr
#> 2020-08-19-Saturn  19h 51m 45s -22* 47' 10''  99.9 -101.2  9.14 18.1  0.9   Sgr
#> 2020-08-19-Uranus   2h 35m 15s  14* 43' 22''  99.9   72.1 19.54  3.4  5.8   Ari
#> 2020-08-19-Neptune 23h 21m 47s  -6* 41' 43'' 100.0   69.5 29.04  2.1  7.8   Aqr
#> 2020-08-19-Pluto   19h  0m 14s -22* 50' 46'' 100.0  -94.2 32.24  0.3 14.1   Sgr

class(planet_df)
#> [1] "data.frame"
```